# Move content from blogspot to custom blog with 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, blogspot

I have found many questions regarding using custom domain for blogspot blog, however, my client wants to leave blogspot and use custom CMS solution on own domain. The data migration is not a problem, but is there any way how can I ensure that all existing links would work (with 301 redirect)? Ideally without specifying redirect for every single article - there is many of them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mapping between old urls and new urls. With this mapping you can implement all required redirects. You can use php or any other language, not only .htaccess. Then you can check all redirect chains with Screaming Frog: http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/audit-redirects/

Comment: You're right you can't use php on blogspot. The only way to set redirect is from admin panel: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2472689?hl=en But you can automate this task with some automation tools.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in my original post. And I also checked that you can only redirect within your blog on Blogger.com, not outside.